# How do you generate (business) month ends/starts for a specific range?

Tags: r

I'm interested in generating a sequence of month ends or starts for a range of time. Even better if the dates are business days where they won't fall on Sunday or Saturday. How do you do this in R?

Answer (score 3):

Here's two functions that I use for that task:

```
library(lubridate)
# returns a sequence of Business Month Ends between two inputs (inclusive)
# or for the one input

GetBizMonthEndFor <- function(dateChar1, dateChar2 = dateChar1){
  # generate the sequence of month starts
  dateChar <- seq(floor_date(as.Date(dateChar1), unit = "month"), 
                  floor_date(as.Date(dateChar2), unit = "month"), 
                  by = "month")
  # add a month to each sequence element and subtract a day           
  dateChar <- dateChar  + months(1) - days(1)
  # if the day is saturday or sunday, subtract a day or two to hit the 
  # previous friday
  dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 1] <- dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 1] - days(2)
  dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 7] <- dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 7] - days(1)
  dateChar
} 



# returns a sequence of Business Month Starts between two inputs (inclusive)
# or for the one input
GetBizMonthStartFor <- function(dateChar1, dateChar2 = dateChar1){
  # generate the sequence of month starts
  dateChar <- seq(floor_date(as.Date(dateChar1), unit = "month"), 
                  floor_date(as.Date(dateChar2), unit = "month"), 
                  by = "month")
  # January 1 is a holiday, so if the month start is january 1, make
  # January 2 the business month start
  dateChar[month(dateChar) == 1 & day(dateChar) == 1] <- 
      dateChar[month(dateChar) == 1 & day(dateChar) == 1] + days(1)
  # If the day is a saturday or sunday, add a day or two to hit the next
  # monday
  dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 1] <- dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 1] + days(1)
  dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 7] <- dateChar[wday(dateChar) == 7] + days(2)

  dateChar
}
```

Note that the business month start has a 'Global Business Day' logic to it. If the day is New Years, then it isn't a business day. You can remove that to just have business days depend on weekdays. Now to showing that they work:

```
> GetBizMonthEndFor("2015-01-12", "2015-10-12")
[1] "2015-01-30" "2015-02-27" "2015-03-31" "2015-04-30" "2015-05-29" "2015-06-30"
[7] "2015-07-31" "2015-08-31" "2015-09-30" "2015-10-30"
```

Note that the inputs dates' day doesn't matter, it takes the months of the inputs and changes them to be the ends of the sequence of months. I haven't put logic in yet to make them only include month end/start dates between the input values, but it's not a hard fix. Something that IS added, though, is the ability to check a date's month end/start by just using one input instead of two.

```
> GetBizMonthStartFor("2015-11-01")
[1] "2015-11-02"
```